# How to get JavaScript to rotate through a series if images

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having an issues where I cannot get my code to rotate multiple images in a cycle for my image gallery (just a bunch of images i got on google). I can however to get 1 image to cycle through the images but everything iv tried to get it to work with more than one has failed. Any help/ tips would be useful. Im in college for web development and i understand the basics of javascript it just seems when it comes to creating applications i have a bit of trouble.

Here is a link to my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zer0pr0x/gz7Ld/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = document.images;
    // Holds the image collection
    var counter = 0;

    var imgArray = [];
    imgArray[0] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img1.png";
    imgArray[1] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img2.jpg";
    imgArray[2] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img3.png";
    imgArray[3] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img4.jpg";
    imgArray[4] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img5.jpg";
    imgArray[5] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img6.png";
    imgArray[6] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img7.jpg";
    imgArray[7] = "http://www.zeroprox.tk/temp/images/img8.png";

    $("#left-arrow").click(function () {
        if (counter < 0) {
             counter = imgArray[counter] - 1;   
        } else {
             counter--;   
        }

        img[1].src = imgArray[counter];
    });
    // Left arrow... Previous

    $("#right-arrow").click(function () {
        counter = (counter + 1) % imgArray.length;

        img[1].src = imgArray[counter];
    });
    // right arrow... Next
});
```

Comment: please set time interval for that function.

Comment: Why do i need a time interval? I dont want the image to change automaticly only when the user clicks on the arrows to view the other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gz7Ld/4/)

Check this, it should solve your problem ;)

You were replacing every time the same image, now creates a new one and remove another.

Also added div#imagelist to use as a image container and access easier from JavaScript

```
var newImg = $(document.createElement("img"));
newImg.attr("src",imgArray[counter]);
$("#imagelist img").last().remove();
$("#imagelist").prepend(newImg);
```

Comment: Okay cool I see what you did there. I was actually thinking about trying to use the createElement method somehow but wasn't sure how to implement it (im new to jquery/dom just learned it a few weeks ago). Thanks a ton!